# is ther any alternative way for doing chain filtering in django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I have a django model named news and another django model named tag that there is a many to many relationship between them. But when I want to filter my news models by several tags, i need to do chain filtering and it is not useful when i am trying to filter news by a list of tags. is there any other way to do that?

this is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name

class news(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(tag)
    source = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and this is the way that i use to filter news:

```
>>> news.objects.filter(tags__tag_name='tech').filter(tags__tag_name='politic')
```

instead of this i want to do something like this:

```
>>> news.objects.filter(tags__tag_name__contains=['tech', 'plitics'])
```

and i have to mention that i am using sqlite database and i cannot change my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q

tags_to_filter = ['tech', 'politics']
query = Q()
for tag in tags_to_filter:
    query |= Q(tags__tag_name=tag)

filtered_news = news.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: tags_to_filter = ['tech', 'politics']
tag_ids = Tag.objects.filter(tag_name__in=tags_to_filter).values_list('id', flat=True)

# Chain filter operations to get news with the desired tags
filtered_news = News.objects.filter(tags__id__in=tag_ids).distinct()

Comment: i did the first method and i did & instead of | because i want all tags to be in news but it doesn't work correctly. i have a news instance with both 'tech' and 'politics' tag but it couldn't retrieve it for me.